# Cuando accedo a mi App Vue desde el servidor 'NetWork' me da error: Network Error

Tags: vue.js

tengo una app que el front esta en vujs y el back en laravel

Si accedo desde mi pc (donde esta la api y el front ) todo funciona ok ya que tiro de localhost. Pero cuando intento acceder a la app de vue desde fuera de mi pc, como puede ser mi movil, mediante la ip que me crea :

```
  App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:8080/
  - Network: http://192.168.0.100:8080/
```

(La que pone **Network**)

Me da error, le he puesto un alert para ver que me dice desde el movil y me dice simplemente **Network errror** pero tiene pinta de ser que no detecta la ip o que no le da permisos mejor dicho.

Mi app de laravel esta en esa ip: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`

He probado con esto desde vuejs (dentro de la instancia de **new Vue** ):

```
...
  devServer: {
    port: 80,
    host: '0.0.0.0'
  },
...
```

Pero ni aun asi va, no se exactamente que deberia mostraros como evidencia de lo qu estoy haciendo, mi vuex es este :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import axios from "axios";
import {router} from "../main";


Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state:{
        auth_user:{},
        users:[],
        messages: [
            // {
            //   content: "The only failure is not to try"
            // }, {
            //   content: "I grew up in Vancouver, man. That's where more than half of my style comes from."
            // }, {
            //   content: "There's nothing glorious in dying. Anyone can do it."
            // }
        ],
        backend_url_base:' http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/'
    },
    mutations:{
        setAuth(state,{user,token}){

            this.commit('setAuthUser',user);
            this.commit('setToken',token);
        },
        setAuthUser(state, user){
            state.auth_user = user;
        },
        setToken(state,token){
            localStorage.setItem('token',token);
        },
        clearAuth(state){
            state.auth_user = null;
            state.token= null;
        },
        addMessage(state,newMessage){
            state.messages.push(newMessage);
        },
        addMessages(state,newMessages){
            newMessages.forEach((message)=>this.addMessage(message));
        },
    },
    getters:{
        getAuthUser: state => state.auth_user,
        getUsers: state => state.users,
        getMessages: state => state.messages,
        getUrlBase: state => state.backend_url_base,
        getToken: state => {
            let token = null;

            if (state.auth_user && localStorage.getItem('token')){
                token = localStorage.getItem('token');
            }

            return token;
        },

        getUrl: state => subUrl =>state.backend_url_base+subUrl,
    },
    setters:{
        setCurrentMessage(state,message){
            state.current_message = message;
        }
    },
    actions:{
        login({commit,getters},user){
            let url = getters.getUrlBase+'user/login';
            axios.post(url,user)
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response.data);
                    if (response.status == 200){
                        let user = response.data.user;
                        let token = response.data.token;
                        commit('setAuth',{user,token});
                    }
                    router.push('/chat');
                })
                .catch((error)=>{
                    console.log('error al iniciar sesion',error);
                    router.push('/login');
                    alert(error)
                });

        },

        sendMessage({getters},message){
            let subUrl = 'message/send';
            let url = getters.getUrl(subUrl);
            let token = getters.getToken;
            let headers =  {Authorization: 'Bearer '+token};

            return axios.post(url, {message}, {headers});
        }
    }
});
```

Si os fijais tengo puesto en vuex el server, que ese en principio no cambia, me conecto a mi app de vuejs desde afuera del pc, pero ya luego ella se conecta con el localhost, entiendo yo que ahi no hay problemas. El caso es que desde **Local** funciona, y desde **Network** no

El error lo he trycaatcheado para que me de un alert con el erro, pero solo me da **Network error**

Comment: Que quieres hacer concretamente?

Comment: @NicolasAldana pues a ver, si tiro `php artisan serve` (laravel) y `npm run serve` (vuejs) tira OK, pero si quiero acceder desde afuera usando `php artisan serve --host ip` pues salta el CORS, y como esto es un chat que estoy haciendo quiero probar  a conectarme desde el propio pc con una cuenta y desde el movil desde otra para testear cosas. Pero al abrir el server con el `--host` salta el CORS, no se porque. Por tanto no me deja conectarme desde el server --host de laravel con la ip del serve del vuejs (en ambos casos los servers que no son localhost)

Comment: si quieres acceder desde fuera no uses el server de laravel, tienes dos opciones, o crear un virtual host directo en windows o trabajar con un entorno como laragon, vagrant etc...

Comment: @NicolasAldana con xamp valdria ?

Comment: te recomiendo mejor usar laragon que genera url amigables y los host se crean automaticamente